# Are Generic lists stored on the stack or the heap in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, list, memory-management

Are Generic lists stored on the stack Or the heap?

#### example

```
//List of Ints
List<int> myInts = new List<int>();
myInts.Add(5);
myInts.Add(10);
myInts.Add(20);
```

Is `myInts` stored on the stack or the heap? If I add an `int` to the list, does boxing or unboxing occur?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`List<T>` is a reference type. Internally it uses `T[]`. Array is a reference type. Instances of reference types are stored on the heap. Since the list in your example is a `List<int>` it can only hold `int`s and no boxing occurs. Boxing occurs if you need to treat a value type as a reference type.

Comment: Hi Brain, can you please explain me how exactly memory allocation takes place for this List<int>? Is it mean that added Ints are value types, so they will be stored on stack and then where referance of myInts will be pointing?

Comment: @Tanuja: The list itself and all its contents will be stored on the heap. Your reference will point to the list instance on the heap. Value types are stored on the heap if they are part of a reference type (e.g. an int field of a class) or stored in an array.

Answer (score 7):

There is no concept of "heap" or "stack" when creating objects in C# or .NET. While the list is stored on the heap, that is really an implementation detail of how the CLR manages its memory.

There is no boxing or unboxing going on here. That is the advantage of using the generic `List` class over the non-generic `ArrayList`. When a new instance of `List<int>` is created, it is as if you wrote a class with the sole purpose of managing a list of `int`. There is not even any casting going on behind the scenes when an `int` is retrieved from the list.

Comment: It might be an implementation detail, but the language specification does mention that instances of reference types are stored on the heap and value types are not.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx

Comment: @Brian, but that's only part of the story. Where is a value type field of a reference type object stored? With the object. And the larger point is that it could all change in a hypothetical future version.

Comment: @Anthony: I know. I wasn't try to explain how things are stored. I was simply pointing out the the language specification covers this a number of times. Please notice that I didn't say that value types are stored on the stack, but simply that they do not incur heap allocation which is the wording used in the spec.

Answer (score 0):

For structs like `int`, the generic list is getting specialized and therefore no boxing/unboxing is required.

Note that the values themselves are stored in a backing array of the `List` nevertheless.